# Elasticsearch URL problems

Tags: url, elasticsearch

I am trying to return more values using elastic search and i am getting an error with this url.
The error just says error the URL i am trying to post to is:

```
http:/someserver.com/elasticSearch/media/_search?q=bowls-d{'from' : 0, 'size' : 100}
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the URL this, URL does work but i only get the default 10 hits back:

```
http:/someserver.com/elasticSearch/media/_search?q=bowls
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
http:/someserver.com/elasticSearch/media/_search?q=bowls&from=0&size=100
```